# Pass an argument in the form of a character vector in order to use it later inside the select argument of the `subset()` function

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to pass an argument in the form of a character vector (called `keep_col`) in order to use it later inside the select argument of the `subset()` function, and all of this is inside a bigger function called `early_prep()` I created.
Bellow is the relevant part of my code.

```
early_prep <- function(file_name, results_name, id = NULL ,keep_rows =  FALSE, keep_col = FALSE, within_vars = c(), reaction_time = NULL, accuracy = NULL, clear_all = FALSE, decimal_places = 4){

  if (clear_all %in% TRUE){
    # Removes all objects form the console
    rm(list = ls())
  }

  # Call read_data() function
  read_data(file_name)

  if (keep_rows != FALSE) {
    raw_data <<- subset(raw_data, eval(parse(text = keep_rows)))
    # Print to console
    print("#### Deleting unnecesarry rows in raw_data ####", quote = FALSE)
  }

  if (keep_col != FALSE) {
    raw_data <<- subset(raw_data, select = keep_col)
   # Print to console
    print("#### Deleting unnecesarry columns in raw_data ####", quote = FALSE)
  }
}
```

The problem is when I call `early_prep(file_name ="n44.txt", keep_col = c("subject", "soa", "congruency"))` I get the following warning message:

```
> early_prep(file_name = "n44.txt", keep_col = c("subject", "soa", "congruency"))
[1] #### Reading txt file ####
[1] #### Deleting unnecesarry columns in raw_data ####
Warning message:
In if (keep_col != FALSE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does anyone have an idea about how I can solve this problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Best,

Ayala

Comment: Do not use `subset` for this. It's a convenience function for interactive use and its documentation (see `help("subset")`) warns explicitly against using it inside other functions. You should use `[` instead (read `help("[")`). Also, do not use `<<-`. Let `early_prep` return the subset and do `raw_data <- early_prep(<your arguments>)`.

Comment: Also, you could change the `keep_rows`/`keep_col` defaults to `NULL` and test `!is.null(keep_col)` in the `if` condition to avoid the warning.

Comment: @Roland Thank you so much for your help! I now use `[` instead of `subset()`, and `NULL` default values for `keep_rows` and `keep_col`. Regarding the use of `<<-` I understand it's meaning and for reasons I didn't specify in my question the use of `<<-` fulfills what I want to accomplish.  Thanks again!